# Running docfx to generate documentation against a .net standard 2.0 project - msbuild error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, docfx

I have a .net standard 2.0 class library.  I have both VS 2017 and VS 2017 preview (for net core 2.0) installed.

I am trying to run docfx to generate documentation for my library.

I first faced an issue where I got the following message:

c:\docfx\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props

It appeared this was because when docfx ran MSBuild it could not find the dot net core 2.0 preview SDK.  I found this could be fixed by creating an environment variable called MSBuildDSKsPath and setting it to the appropriate value.  That got me past the above error and now I'm stuck with this error:

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\2.0\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found.

This is coming from the Sdk.props file because in that file is this reference:

The MSBuildExtensionsPath value is right, but is appears the MSBuildToolsVersion is wrong.  It should be 14 or 15 (not sure which, but those are what I have installed).

I tried a few things.  I tried setting the MSBuildToolsVersion in the docfx.json file, and I also tried setting an MSBuildToolsVersion environment variable.  Neither work.

Any suggestions on how to get this to run?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/1752#issuecomment-308909959) tracking this. Current workaround is to set `env.MSBuildSDKsPath` to the right place, e.g. `$ set MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-rc4-004771\Sdks`

Answer (score 0):

maybe set the `ToolsVersion` in csproj file can work
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="14.0">`
the version value must be available